# Find all pairs of complex numbers (x,y) satisfying $xy=-1$ and $x^3-y^3=-1$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, complex-numbers

the problem asks me to find all pairs of complex numbers (x,y) satisfying $xy=-1$ and $x^3-y^3=-1$ simultaneously. I set the two equations to equal each other which yields
$x^3-xy-y^3=0$ but from this point on on im stuck on how i would solve for $x$ and $y$. any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: $xy=-1$ yields $y=-1/x$, which you can substitute into the other equation.

Comment: yes but then i get $x^6+x^3+1$ which has no solutions

Comment: whats the reasoning for that?

Comment: Of course $x^6+x^3+1=0$ has solutions. Write it as $u^2+u+1=0$ where $u=x^3$ and solve the quadratic. Almost the same as Oscar's answer (modulo Vieta's identities). With experience, you can recognize $u^2+u+1$ as the minimal polynomial of a primitive cube root of unity, so the solutions to this equation are the primitive $3\cdot 3=9$th roots of unity. (Of course if you want the answer in radicals you'll need to solve the quadratic for $u$, as mentioned.)

Comment: @anon, placed answer fitting your comment. My original suggestion, just before skrrrt saying "whats the reasoning for that?" was to multiply $x^6 + x^3 + 1$ by $x^3 - 1.$  I deleted my comment after skrrrt refused to attempt my suggestion. It's the next day, I got back some patience.

Comment: Arriving by anon's suggestion at $ x^3 + x^{-3} = -1$ which is $2\cosh(3 \ln(x))=-1$; then  $ x =  \exp(\text{acosh}(-1/2)/3) $

Comment: Hmm, stupid- my previous comment. It does not give "all solutions" - at least not explicitely...

Answer (score 4):

You have

$(x^3)(-y^3)=-(-1)^3=1$

$x^3+(-y^3)=-1$

You are to derive a quadratic equation whose roots are $x^3,-y^3$.  Pick either root as $x^3$, take cube roots and derive the value of $y$ for each $x$ from the product relation.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It seems [that **anon** gave some explanation of the suggestion I made.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533217/find-all-pairs-of-complex-numbers-x-y-satisfying-xy-1-and-x3-y3-1#comment5230866_2533217)

Also, you do have questions using complex numbers, including some with $e^{m \pi i / n}.$

So, your original variable $x$ satisfies $x^6 + x^3 + 1 = 0.$ Note that we have $x^3 \neq 1,$ otherwise we would have $1+1+1=0,$ which is false. Next,
$$ 0 = (x^3 - 1)(x^6 + x^3 + 1) = x^9 - 1. $$ Notice that the comment by anon points out that the solutions $x$ are precisely the primitive 9th roots of unity.

So far, $$ x^9 = 1, \; \; \mbox{but} \; \; \; x^3 \neq 1.  $$
Define $$  \omega = e^{2 \pi i / 9} = \cos \frac{2 \pi}{9} + i \, \sin \frac{2 \pi}{9} \; \; . $$
The six answers to the original problem are $$ x = \omega, \omega^2, \omega^4, \omega^5, \omega^7, \omega^8. $$
In each case we take
$$ y = - \bar{x}.  $$
To be specific, when $x = a + b i,$ we get $y = -a + bi.$
For example, when $x = \omega,$ we get
$$ y = - \cos \frac{2 \pi}{9} + i \, \sin \frac{2 \pi}{9} = e^{7 \pi i / 9} \; \; .  $$